# Universal Control working intermittently between two Macs running macOS 12.6

Tags: macos, keyboard, mouse, universal-control

I’m using a 14” M1 MacBook Pro and an Intel Mac mini, both running macOS 12.6, with Universal Control enabled so that I can share an external Magic Keyboard and Magic Mouse between both Macs. The keyboard and mouse are connected via Bluetooth to the MacBook Pro and then “linked” to the Mac mini, which is connected to an external display.

Every so often, the MacBook Pro seems to “forget” that the Mac mini is there: the keyboard and mouse abruptly stop working with it, and System Preferences > Displays will only show the settings for the MacBook Pro’s display. This will happen even if I’m actively using the mouse and keyboard with the Mac mini! Then, after waiting 20-30 seconds, it’ll suddenly reappear and everything will start working again, until some point later when the same cycle repeats.

All of the troubleshooting steps I can find mention things like ensuring both Macs are on the same wifi network, signed into the same iCloud account, etc. But I know I have everything set up correctly and meet all the requirements for Universal Control because *it does work* most of the time. It’s not that I can’t get it to work at all; it’s that it periodically stops working for no apparent reason.

Is it just flaky and I’m out of luck?

Comment: You’re not alone.  Most of these [“universal control working”](https://apple.stackexchange.com/search?q=Universal+control+working+) questions are about similar experiences.

Comment: Still a persistent issue on mac os 13.3. Works reliably all day every day between two macbook pros, but is flaky when connected to my mac mini. An upgrade from a 2018 i3 to an m1 mac mini didn't even resolve the issue.